# Адаптивный дизайн или mobile version

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста опытные люди: что вообще лучше написать сайт с адаптивным дизайном для поддержки телефонами и планшетами или написать мобильную версию сайта, я имею ввиду есть например сайт http://test.ru для настольных компов, а еще есть например http://m.test.ru. А при загрузке отслеживать разрешение экрана и редиректить куда надо.
В css у меня только основы. Мне кажется что проще писать мобильную версию отдельно, чем адаптивный, или я ошибаюсь???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По мне адаптивный лучше. Да, он может быть сложнее в разработке, но он гораздо легче в обслуживании, если у вас один сайт и несколько его версий, всегда будет вероятность, что при обновлении контента версии начнут различаться. Обслуживать один сайт, вместо двух (если добавляются версии, трех и далее) легче и менее трудоемко. В результате больше времени на первичную разработку, меньше времени на обслуживание.

Но есть и третий вариант, можно посмотреть вариант RESS, еще сложнее в разработке, но потом сплошная радость жизни.

Думаю, что любой вариант имеет место быть, скорее выбор стоит делать исходя из того сколько нужно потрать на разработку и какой должен быть результат и как его поддерживать. Например если поддержка не требуется вовсе, можно не тратить время, а склепать несколько версий сайта, если контент всегда обслуживается, то адаптивный, а лучшее RESS и т. д.